# "-[UIBarButtonItem selectedSegmentIndex]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" for segmented control in top UIBar

Tags: swift, crash, uibarbuttonitem, uisegmentedcontrol, ibaction

I am using Swift 4. I have a segmented control on the right of a top `UINavigationBar` like so:

[image: segmented control on UIBar]

When I create an outlet from the Storyboard to my code, by default it wants it to be a `UIBarButtonItem`, but for my action I cannot access `selectedSegmentIndex` without making it a `UISegmentedControl`.

So I make my outlet like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var saveAsControl: UISegmentedControl!
```

My action, as a test, is this:

```
@IBAction func saveAsTypeAction(_ sender: Any) {

    print("tapped")

    switch saveAsControl.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0:
        print("video selected")
    case 1:
        print("gif selected")
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

If I tap the segmented control, the debugger crashes and has the message:

> `-[UIBarButtonItem selectedSegmentIndex]`: unrecognized selector sent to instance

So I have no idea how to get the segmented control working. Seems like it has something to do with the `UINavigationBar`, but I have no idea why it would be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely wired up your outlets wrong. Here is the correct setup:

[image: Segmented control - correct setup]

[image: View hierarchy]

Note that **both the outlet and the action** are wired to the segmented control and not the bar button itself.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I must have been connecting the bar button item instead of the segmented control.